# XML query issue

Tags: c#, xml

I am trying to get some data from xml file from my C# coding.

How can I get the data of **claim** node if the following **claim-ib-info** *node does not contain* **withdrawn** node.

If you are not clear about my question, let me know.

I don't know much about XML and thanks in advance.

```
<info>
    <claim kind="national" sequence="1">
        <country>UK</country>
        <number>66</number>
        <date>20080602</date>
    </claim>
    <claim-ib-info>
        <received-at>
            <date>20090610</date>
        </received-at>
    </claim-ib-info>


    <claim kind="national" sequence="2">
        <country>US</country>
        <number>125</number>
        <date>20080501</date>
    </claim>
    <claim-ib-info>
        <withdrawn>
            <date>20100721</date>
        </withdrawn>
    </claim-ib-info>


    <claim kind="national" sequence="3">
        <country>TH</country>
        <number>61</number>
        <date>20090316</date>
    </claim>
    <claim-ib-info>
        <received-at>
            <date>20090610</date>
        </received-at>
    </claim-ib-info>


    <claim kind="national" sequence="4">
        <country>MY</country>
        <number>66</number>
        <date>20090209</date>
    </claim>
    <claim-ib-info>
        <withdrawn>
            <date>20101221</date>
        </withdrawn>
    </claim-ib-info>
</info>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to learn and use [Linq to XML.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387098.aspx)

```
var list = from ele in XDocument.Load(@"c:\files.xml").Descendants("claim-ib-info")
                    where ele.Element("withdrawn")!=null
                   select ele.PreviousNode  ;

foreach (var t in list)
{
    Console.WriteLine(t);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend learning XPath first.  XPath (unlike LINQ) is an open technology; you can use it on any platform, with any XML-aware language and library:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d271ytdx.aspx